# Populating an input with JavaScript/jQuery with data from _MySql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on a website that is heavily based on a database and I've run into a problem with retrieving information from it.

What I want to achieve:
User clicks on a button, a dialog opens - done
The select input inside the dialog is populated with options from the database - ?

I've tried with AJAX calls from jQuery, but all I get is an error inside the Google Chrome console
`POST http://ematura.gcc.si/pages/admin/populate/inc.admin.content.populate.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Is there any other way I can get data from the DB?

Edit:
This is my jQuery code (one select is prepopulated  in code)

```
$("#add_subject").change(function()
    {
        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../pages/admin/populate/inc.admin.content.populate.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                $("#add_content").show();
                $("#add_content").html(html);
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

This is the inc.admin.content.populate.php

```
if($_POST['id'])
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    global $mysqli;

    if($query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT naslov,vsebina_id FROM table_vsebine WHERE predmet_id=?")){
        $query->bind_param('i',$id);
        if($query->execute()){
            $query->bind_result($naslov,$vsebine_id);
            $query->store_result();

            echo '<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Izberi vsebino</option>';
            while($row = $query->fetch()){
             echo '<option value="'.$vsebine_id.'">'.$naslov.'</option>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why does your script send the page to the client without the select populated?

Comment: please show us your code. also before you can retrieve data from database using jquery you must have an identifier or selected data.

Comment: So what does your server side code look like?  Posting to an arbitrary URL doesn't tell us anything unless we have access to your API.